# Getting Organization name from domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I search a lot but could not find a way how to get Organization name(Company) from domain name or Email Address. 
   For example

> ```
>  Email/domain                    Organization Name
> ```
>
> 1. "person1@msn.com"  ------>        "Microsoft"
>   2. "person2@ecb.com"  ------>        "European Central Bank"
>   3. "www.live.com"     ------>        "Hotmail"

I suspect there should be gem which could do this.If Anyone know please suggest me i will very thankful. And if you have other suggestion how to do this.

Comment: You could possibly parse the whois record for the domain, or scrape home pages for information.

Comment: The TLD has no requirement to look like the name of the owning entity so those are of little help directly. You can use whois records but those are not necessarily available. And, whois records vary wildly, depending on the registrar. A gem isn't going to cover the range of formats in the wild, only the most popular ones, so don't be surprised with gaps and failures. It's an ugly, or beautiful, fact of the internet, depending on where you stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `whois` gem.

```
require 'whois'
client = Whois::Client.new
record = client.lookup("msn.com")
record.properties[:registrant_contacts].first.organization
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need to adjust your code so that it will not raise an error when the match result is `nil`.

Comment: The idea was not to offer bullet proof code but rather to show how the gem worked. Anyone actually incorporating it into their project should of course read the documentation on the gem usage and handle exceptional cases.

Comment: I agree that the OP lacks effort in the question. Then you could have just introduced the gem as a comment to the question. That would have been enough.

Comment: Sorry to say But I am unable to install 'whois' gem and maybe i am getting so much problem cause i am new to ruby on rails and dont know much about it and Unfortunately i get this task in my project. I am using 'ruby 1.8.7' and 'Rails 2.3.2'. I am getting following error in console while trying "gem install whois"                  ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'whois' (>= 0) in any repository                                                         first time i am getting this error while installing any gem. Please Help.

Comment: Yes, the Gem readme specifies a requirement of Ruby >= 1.9.2. On GitHub: https://github.com/weppos/whois. If you are new to ruby and rails, I'd highly suggest not starting with 1.8.7 and 2.3.2. Both of those are retired technologies.